# emulator stop application unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I have created an application. The code is fine with no error but while running on the emulator gives message 'The application has stopped unexpectedly'

Manifest code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.gregjacobs.enhancedquotes">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name=".QuotesMain" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuoteEdit" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
</application>
</manifest> 
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>-->
<!--<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
<!--      package="com.gregjacobs.enhancedquotes"-->
<!--      android:versionCode="1"-->
<!--      android:versionName="1.0">-->
<!--    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">-->
<!--        <activity android:name=".quotes"-->
<!--                  android:label="@string/app_name">-->
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->
<!--        </activity>-->
<!---->
<!--    </application>-->
<!---->
<!---->
<!--</manifest> -->
```

[logcat link](http://tinypic.com/r/2n1v0ck/6)

Comment: What's on line 51 in QuotesMain.java? According to your logcat, that's where the error occure

Comment: On line 51 in QuotesMain.java there is a declaration

 private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

Comment: Could you post QuotesMain.java? Because that line cannot be the source of the error. If you look at your logcat the error is located inside `onCreate()`. You shouldn't even be able to compile if you declare a static variable inside a method.